# Bitwise operators with increment decrement

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

What is the output of this C code?

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void main()

    {

        int a = 5, b = -7, c = 0, d;

        d = ++a && ++b || ++c;

        printf("\n%d%d%d%d", a, b, c, d);

    }
```

The answere is 6 -6 0 1.
I don't understand how as the precedence of logical AND is more than OR.

Comment: There are no bitwise operators here.

Answer (score 2):

What happens is that `a` is incermented by 1 as well as `b` using `++a, ++b`.
The outcome of `++a && ++b` is true (which equlas 1) and that is exactly what `d` gets.

Because it reads `true || ++c` it does not check the right handside since the result is clearly `true`, that is why c equlas 0.